# Python, last element cut

Tags: python

Well problem was that my original input is:

```
x=[['1', '7', 'gg'], ['1.5', '8', 'as']...]
```

I need just cut last element in every row.

I try to cut last element in matrix with that:

```
hl=x[:,:-1]
```

BUT THIS IS NOT WORKING, so I try in this way:

```
kl=array(x) 
hl=x[:,:-1]
```

Now I get:

```
[['1' '7']
 ['1.5' '8']]
```

Instead of:
[['1' , '7']
 ['1.5' , '8']]

Any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> x=[['1', '7', 'gg'], ['1.5', '8', 'as']]
>>> [s[:-1] for s in x]
[['1', '7'], ['1.5', '8']]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
for row in x:
    del row[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
h1 = [el[:-1] for el in x]
print h1
```

Output:

> [['1', '7'], ['1.5', '8']]

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [['1', '7', 'gg'], ['1.5', '8', 'as']]

for y in x:
    y.pop()

print x
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `map` function to accomplish this:

```
>>> list(map(lambda i: i[:-1], x))
[['1', '7'], ['1.5', '8']]
```

Though list comprehension is probably a better solution...